# ODBC Schema - How Do I Find Relationships?

Tags: c#, odbc, foreign-key-relationship, relationship

I am currently working on a project that requires fetching database schema through an ODBC connection. Mainly because the source could be an Access database, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.
With this I will recreate the customers schema into a SQL Database.

Everything is working fine, but I am not able to find a way to retrieve the relationships between tables and I could not find anything on MSDN about this. If this cannot be done then I need to know another **generic** way of doing it.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the ODBC API directly, the API [SQLForeignKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be used for this.  However, since you are using OdbcConnection objects, it would be a painful process to use the API for this one task.  Well, for that matter, using the ODBC API directly for anything is a lot of work.

**Edit** I suggested the possibility of using [OdbcConnectionGetSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135852.aspx) with `'ForeignKeys'` as the collection name.  However, I looked into that and, unfortunately, OdbcConnection does not appear to support that collection.

So aside from using SQLForeignKeys directly (or making database-specific calls), it seems that ODBC is not going to provide an easy route to gather that information generically.  If someone can provide an answer with a nice mechanism for doing it, I will delete this answer since its only value at this point is to point out that I don't know how to find the information cleanly.

Comment: I am using .NET's built in OdbcConnecton object and calling GetSchema(). If I am unable get what I need from this object then I may need to resort to calling ODBC APIs. I'll have to figure out how to access these through C# as I am not sure what DLLs they are actually housed in.

Comment: @TyCobb:  I probably could have guessed that is how you were accessing it.  I'll try to see if I can figure out if SQLForeignKeys is used by the OdbcConnection code.  However, I promised my wife I would be home in 13 minutes ... I'm late.  But I just figured out a bug that has plagued me for over a day, so that must be worth something.  In any case, it would be nice if you can avoid using the API directly; those are a *major* hassle to use directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I may go ahead and hit up the ODBC32.dll just to see what I can do with it. You at least got me a plan B.

Comment: @TyCobb:  I added a bit more info in the answer about the GetSchema method (I remembered it on the way home), but I can't actually check it out now. So hopefully, it's not a dead end.  It should be quick to check, though, if you have test code with an OdbcConnection object set up already.

Comment: From what I can find on the internet is that some people have luck with passing in "ForeignKeys" and others do not. Unfortunately I am in the category of it does not work for me =/ I get "The requested collection (ForeignKeys) is not defined."  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @TyCobb: Sorry I couldn't provide anything better.  I have no idea what your constraints are, but you might consider using DbProviderFactory, DbConnection, etc. to "generically" get direct connections to each backend using their native providers and then use the GetSchema methods, which "may" be implemented.  Using those generic objects allows common code to handle most things except for the connection strings (which you likely already have to customize).

Comment: I am marking your post as the answer since it technically can't be done through .NET's OdbcCnnection which I do need to use.